# error handling when unwrapping several try_into calls

Tags: rust

I have a case where I need to parse some different values out from a vector.
I made a function for it, that returns a option, which either should give a option or a None, depending on whether the unwrapping succeeds.

Currently it looks like this:

```
fn extract_edhoc_message(msg : Vec<u8>)-> Option<EdhocMessage>{
    let mtype = msg[0];
    let fcnt = msg[1..3].try_into().unwrap();
    let devaddr = msg[3..7].try_into().unwrap();
    let msg = msg[7..].try_into().unwrap();
    Some(EdhocMessage {
        m_type: mtype,
        fcntup: fcnt,
        devaddr: devaddr,
        edhoc_msg: msg,
    })
}
```

But, I would like to be able to return a None, if any of the unwrap calls fail.

I can do that by pattern matching on each of them, and then explicitly return a None, if anything fails, but that would a lot of repeated code.

Is there any way to say something like:

```
"if any of these unwraps fail, return a None?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `?` does. It's even shorter than the `.unwrap()` version:

```rust
fn extract_error_message(msg: Vec<u8>) -> Option<EdhocMessage> {
  let m_type = msg[0];
  let fcntup = msg[1..3].try_into().ok()?;
  let devaddr = msg[3..7].try_into().ok()?;
  let edhoc_msg = msg[7..].try_into().ok()?;
  Some(EdhocMessage {
    m_type,
    fcntup,
    devaddr,
    edhoc_msg
  })
}
```

See [this relevant part](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#shortcuts-for-panic-on-error-unwrap-and-expect) of the Rust Book.

Comment: ah yeah, there's one issue though . The above code gives the error `error: the ? operator can only be used on Options, not Results, in a function that returns Option`
Which i guess is because the try_into thing returns a result

Comment: @Grazosi You can convert a `Result<T, _>` into an `Option<T>` using `.ok()`. I've updated the answer.